# How can I create a Java .app bundle for Max OS X on my windows build machine

Tags: java, macos, installation, swt, dmg

I have a SWT based Java application that works on Windows, Mac OS and Linux.  I develop it on my Windows machine and have a tester with Linux and a tester with a Mac.  Currently my process creates a runnable .jar file for each platform on my Windows machine (which references the platform specific .jar and lib files from Eclipse.org).  I have a working installer for Windows - also produced by the build on the windows machine.  I want to create a standard Mac OS installer for my Mac users.  The right way to do that appears to be to create a .app bundle and distribute it via a dmg file.  This has not being going well.  I have a working Java app that uses SWT and can be run from the command line, on all platforms.  I have a way of building a .dmg on Windows.  But so far all my attempts to get a .app bundle to work have failed.

I started by following this tutorial: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/

But when running my application I get an error saying that applications for the Power PC are not supported.  That is using the same binaries that work from the command line using java -jar so the problem must be in the the way I am bundling.  The sample Hello app from the page also fails to work but with a different error message.

I have been searching all day and found this promising talk: http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2891&sl=72

In that talk the speaker says there will be a way to create a Mac OS .app bundle on any platform using a standard java launcher.  But I cannot find any such thing released yet.

I found this post that also looks promising: http://www.intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/

But this recipe says it will not work except by building on a Mac OS machine.

What I want to do is create a .app bundle for Mac OS X on my windows machine along with the Windows install and the Linux install.  It would be preferable to also include a jre as part of the app bundle (which I already have working for Windows and Linux).  I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)?

The .app is just a directory with a special structure a few special files.  Once you have it created, you'll only need to update the JAR each time you build, which can be found here: MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Java/MyJar.jar.

There will also be a few Java-specific properties in My.app/Contents/Info.plist, but you probably won't need to change these from how you initially set them up.

Comment: Yes, I know and getting that template set of special files and java specific properties is what is eluding me.  The links to examples I looked at do *not* work.  I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @IanLeslie Apple used to have an app called JarBundler which you could use to package your Java executable, but they have discontinued it.  I believe the link I posted is Oracle's replacement solution to create the .app.

Comment: Thanks @whiskeyspider.  I have successfully build a Swing app as a bundle and am now working on my SWT app.

Comment: Thanks for the Jar Bundler tip @whiskeyspider. I went to spotlight and searched for "jarbundler" and found a folder with that name. Inside is a tool that asked me for the jar file and an icon and then created the bundle. The hardest part was converting a png into icns.